# Laravel eloquent sorts data from largest to smallest from table relations that do not necessarily have a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

I've a problem when sorts data from largest to smallest from table relations that do not necessarily have a relationship with PHP Laravel Eloquent.

```
Table: items
|---------------------------|
|  id  |  name    |  price  |
|---------------------------|
|  1   |  Samsung |  70.000 |
|  2   |  iPhone  |  90.000 |
|  3   |  Nokia   |  50.000 |
|  4   |  Huawei  |  80.000 |
|  5   |  Xiaomi  |  60.000 |
|  6   |  LG      |  40.000 |
|---------------------------|

Table: sells
|------------------------------------------|
|  id  |  invoice |  total   |  created_at |
|------------------------------------------|
|  1   |   1001   |  720.000 |  2021-10-01 |
|  2   |   1002   |  420.000 |  2021-10-01 |
|  3   |   1003   |   80.000 |  2021-10-15 |
|------------------------------------------|

Table: sell_items
|------------------------------------|
|  id  |  sell_id |  item_id  |  qty |
|------------------------------------|
|  1   |    1     |     1     |   5  |
|  2   |    1     |     2     |   4  |
|  3   |    2     |     3     |   3  |
|  4   |    2     |     2     |   3  |
|  5   |    3     |     4     |   1  |
|------------------------------------|
```

and I will only take 5 data from the largest.

```
Top Product:
|--------------------------------|
|  No  |  Product |  Total (Qty) |
|--------------------------------|
|  1   |  iPhone  |      7       |
|  2   |  Samsung |      4       |
|  3   |  Nokia   |      3       |
|  4   |  Huawei  |      1       |
|  5   |  Xiaomi  |      0       |
|--------------------------------|
```

My syntax:

```
$thisYear = date('Y');
$topProduct = SellItem::whereHas('sells', function($p) use ($thisYear) {
                                        $p->whereYear('created_at', $thisYear)
                                    })
                        ->whereHas('items')
                ->select('id', 'name', DB::raw('sum('qty') as total'))->take(5)->orderBy('total', 'desc')->get();
```

please help me to solve it.

Comment: Is `SellItem` a pivot model for the `sell_items` table or is it a model for the `items` table?

Comment: @Erin SellItem is sell_items table.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- `SellItem` is a model for the pivot table `sell_items`
- `Item` is a model on table `items`
- `Sell` is a model on table `sells`
- `SellItem` has a `BelongsTo` relationship `item` with `Item`
- `SellItem` has a `BelongsTo` relationship `sell` with `Sell`

With the relationships set in the model classes, you can do something like this:

```
$topProducts = SellItem::has('item')
   ->with('item')
   ->whereHas('sell', function ($query) {
     $query->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'));
   })
   ->groupBy('item_id')
   ->withSum('qty as total')
   ->orderByDesc('total')
   ->get();
   ->map( function ($sell) {
      return $sell->item;
   });
```